# $\dfrac{1}{T}\underset{t = 0}{\overset{T - 1}{\sum}}xP^t$ converges

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, stochastic-matrices

I'm trying to proof that $\dfrac{1}{T}\underset{t = 0}{\overset{T - 1}{\sum}}xP^t$, where x is stochastic vector, P is stochastic matrix, converges. I understand that if there are no eigenvalues of $\pi = \dfrac{1}{T}\underset{t = 0}{\overset{T - 1}{\sum}}xP^t$ such that $|\lambda| = 1, \; \lambda \neq 1,$ $\pi$ converges. But I can't understand what if $P$ has eigenvalues $\lambda \neq 1,$ such that $|\lambda| = 1$. Thank you for any help!

Comment: for any $\lambda \neq 1$ do you know how to telescope a finite geometric series?  i.e.  $\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\lambda^j=?$

Comment: $\lambda \dfrac{\lambda^{m} - 1}{\lambda - 1}$?

Comment: there's an extra $\lambda$ in there, but basically yes.  So now for your problem you want to estimate the modulus of the 'average' of that i.e.  $\big\vert \frac{1}{m} \sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\lambda^j\big\vert = \frac{1}{m} \big\vert \dfrac{\lambda^{m} - 1}{\lambda - 1} \big\vert \leq \frac{1}{m}\big\vert \dfrac{2}{\lambda - 1}  \big\vert $  where the upper bound comes from triangle inequality (check).  now $\big\vert \dfrac{2}{\lambda - 1}  \big\vert  = \text{constant}$ i.e. doesn't depend on $m$ and $\frac{1}{m}$ may be made arbitrarily small for large enough $m$, i.e. the upper bound $\to 0$

Comment: okay thank you! but how does it help to my question?

Comment: you wrote "I understand that if there are no eigenvalues.... [with modulus 1 other than than the perron root the cesaro sum converges]".  The above is the extension dealing with other eigenvalues on the unit circle.  The typical finish, assuming irredcuibility, is to look at $B=P-\mathbf \pi \mathbf 1$ and shown that the cesaro sum of $B^j$ tends to zero.  This presupposes you write out the Jordan Form of $B$ and know e.g. that any eigenvalues on the unit circle are semisimple, etc.  i.e. it supposes you know rudiments of Perron-Frobenius Theory.

Comment: note: there are direct probabilistic ways to the result you're looking for... e.g. the result is an immediate consequence of the elementary renewal theorem applied to a delayed renewal process

Comment: Thank you! Is there some place where I can read about it more in detail? Cause I failed to find :(

Comment: do you prefer algebraic or probabilistic approaches?

Comment: probabilistic :)

Comment: for renewal theory, Feller vol 1 2nd or 3rd edition is cheap and something everyone should own -- they pioneered renewal theory with that book so the result may not be transparent.  A nice modern approach :  http://www.randomservices.org/random/renewal/index.html  .   For a middle ground, try the telescoping approach in Grinstead and Snell's book, problem 16 on page 468 https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf  .  I may end up writing that telescope as an answer as it gives *something* simple coherent for future readers

Comment: Thank you so much!